# Access YAML list in Rails translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, rails-i18n

I have the following translation file:

```
ru:
  common:
    age:
      - год
      - года
      - лет
```

and I want to access list items in tranlsation. I tried something like:

```
t('common.age[2]')
```

But it doesn't work. How to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store an array structure in YAML but you can't iterate over one in YAML-land.  YAML is a data serialisation language, and is not meant to contain executable statements ([`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) is a Ruby method call), only data structures.  Executable statements are the responsibility of the programming language you're working with, in your case Ruby.

So, in your case, you need to use `t('common.age')` to first pull out the array from YAML, then iterate over it in Ruby-land:

```
array = t('common.age')
# => ["год", "года", "лет"]
array[2]
# => "лет"
```